# Are these two SQL statements the same? Or at least give the same answer?

Tags: sql, database

```sql
SELECT MID  
FROM Authors, Writes   
WHERE Authors.ID=Writes.ID AND Name = ‘J. R. Hartley’;   

SELECT MID  
FROM Writes  
WHERE W.ID IN     (SELECT A.ID  
                FROM Authors A   
                WHERE A.Name = "J. R. Hartley");
```

Image of how to the DB is setup
https://i.stack.imgur.com/afJTS.jpg

Top is the answer on the mark scheme. Bottom is mine. I think they'll give you the same results but I am not confident. Also is their way better?
Thanks

Comment: databases are no setup through images.... Please specify if this is `mysql` or `sqlite`, it cannot be both!

Comment: @Luuk I know they aren't setup with images its a question from a test. The image shows how you *would* set it up.
Don't mysql and sqlite use the same query langauge? SQL? Or at least very similar and thats all I'm asking about. Are the queries equal

Comment: Then please only tag with `sql`, because the question apears to be about standard use of sql.  (In other words, you are also not adding Oracle, Postgresql, DB2, and they also use sql.....)

Comment: @Luuk okay thanks changed it to remove the other tags

Comment: If you could have co-authors with the same name then the first would list MID twice while the second would not.

Comment: For an idea of how dated that join syntax is, the "new" style is from 92. The old style still works, but varies depending on system, and you'll be harshly judged in interviews for not caring about best practices.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes the 2 queries produce the same results.
The 1st query uses an old style join which you should avoid, if you are starting with SQL.
The proper way to write it is:

```
SELECT MID  
FROM Writes w INNER JOIN Authors a   
ON a.ID = w.ID AND a.Name = 'J. R. Hartley';
```

I prefer the 2nd query, but you should change the operator `IN` with `=` since it is guaranteed that the subquery will return only 1 row (or none):

```
SELECT MID  
FROM Writes  
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM Authors WHERE Name = 'J. R. Hartley');
```

Comment: Thanks. I originally had an "=" but was worried it wasn't good practice as only works for single values

Glad to see my lecturer is teaching us out of date SQL. Or maybe just keeping it simple as we're only first years

Comment: You should use IN when you expect more than 1 rows returned. For example: `WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Authors WHERE Name LIKE '%John%')` for the ids of authors whose name contains "John".

Answer (score 0):

These two queries are NOT the same.  Let me start with the second query:

```
SELECT w.MID  
FROM Writes w 
WHERE W.ID IN (SELECT A.ID  
               FROM Authors A   
               WHERE A.Name = 'J. R. Hartley'
              );
```

This query is guaranteed to never return duplicate rows from `Writes`.

Let me rewrite the first query as a `JOIN` (which is equivalent and should be how you are learning SQL):

```
SELECT w.MID  
FROM Authors a JOIN
     Writes w  
     ON w.ID = a.ID AND a.Name = 'J. R. Hartley';
```

Note that I have qualified the column references.  That is one difference.  The way you wrote the query would generate an error if both tables had a `Name` column.  The `IN` version would not have this issue.

The more important difference is that this could duplicate rows from `Writes`, if `id` is duplicated in `Authors`.  You have not specified that `id` is unique or the primary key, so this is a possibility.

There are circumstances where the two queries you wrote are equivalent.  But there are other circumstances where one runs and the other returns an error.  Or when they do not return the same result set.  Hence, the two are not equivalent.

Comment: Id is obviously the primary key of Authors and the table Writes dos not have a Name column. You should check the link in the question where you see the schema before you posted this answer which is misleading.